# Datastax Bulk Loader for Apache Cassandra not installing

Tags: installation, cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I have followed the instructions in the documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/install/dsbulkInstall.html

However, after doing the following:

```
curl -OL https://downloads.datastax.com/dsbulk/dsbulk-1.6.0.tar.gz
```

and

```
tar -xzvf dsbulk-1.6.0.tar.gz
```

inside an application directory, followed by the command

```
dsbulk --version
```

I get the output

```
Unable to find java 8 (or later) executable. Check JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Im using an AWS ec2 t2.medium instance - do I have to install java on this in order for dsbulk to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DSBulk doesn’t include Java into it, so you need to install Java yourself - via apt, or whatever you use